# How to add SQLFilter to Azure service bus topic subscription

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have a azure service bus topics subscription in azure function.

Below is the code for subscription:
[image]

Topic names: send-not

Subscription: send-idea, send-email

'send-idea' is subscribing to 'send-email' as well due to non availability of any filter. How can I add SQL Filter as below in azure function

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the SQL Filter syntax

```
<function> :=  
      newid() |  
      property(name) | p(name)
```

Also Check the below docs

[Subscription Rule SQL Filter Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-filter).

[Subscription Rule SQL Action Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-rule-action).

Also Find the [SO](http://Check%20the%20SQL%20Filter%20syntax%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cfunction%3E%20:=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20newid()%20%7C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20property(name)%20%7C%20p(name)%20%20Also%20Check%20the%20below%20docs%20%20%5BSubscription%20Rule%20SQL%20Filter%20Syntax%5D(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-filter).%20%5BSubscription%20Rule%20SQL%20Action%20Syntax%5D(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-rule-action).%20%20Also%20Find%20the%20%60SO%20%60%20thread%20with%20related%20discussion.) thread with related discussion.

Comment: Where do I add this in azure function ?